# Hadoop SQL requires a table name to just get the time. How to get the table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

Some Hive derivatives (such as Hadoop) require a table name for an SQL query to get the current time:

```
    SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM ANYTABLE
```

The table name is both irrelevant and superfluous, but is required (other Hive dialects don't allow a FROM clause and some don't care whether there is a FROM clause or not).

The error I'm receiving from Cloudera Hadoop if a FROM clause isn't included:
*[Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while execurint query. Error message from server: Error while processing statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input '' expecting FROM near ')' in from clause*

If any table will do, one can be obtained from "SHOW TABLES". But that requires another query, which I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a generic/system table name that can be used for this? Or another way to query the time without a known table name?

(The Hive implementations that I have discovered that need the FROM clause are Cloudera Hadoop and Horton. Presto and Athena give an error if you use a FROM clause. Other Hive implementations I checked don't care if there's a FROM clause of not.)

Comment: Hive allow you to select without table, what hive version are you using? You should add the error

Comment: Updated with error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks Hive allows you to select without a `FROM` clause.

```
 0: jdbc:hive2://localhost> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 1555423112  |
+-------------+--+
1 row selected (0.204 seconds)

0: jdbc:hive2://localhost> SELECT'foo bar';
+----------+--+
|   _c0    |
+----------+--+
| foo bar  |
+----------+--+
1 row selected (0.855 seconds)
```

If you are still getting an error while trying to select a timestamp, post your error and Hive version.